# fork() vs std::async in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I am new to concepts of asyc and fork, what I understood till now is that the fork() creates chid processes which will run asynchronously.
And the std::async will create a thread from the system pool and launch it asynchronously here if I mention **std::launch::async**.

For instance how does below set of code differs?
1: using std::async

```
std::vector<std::future<void>> result;
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    result. push_back(std::async(std::launch::asyc, foo, var1));
}

for( auto e : result) 
    e.get();
```

2nd: Using fork()

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){ 
    if(fork()==0){
        foo(var1);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

Assume the foo function return type is void, and the arguments are passed as reference or pointers.

Comment: You're really asking about the difference between spawning processes and spawning threads.  What does your operating systems book say about these topics?

Comment: Well for one this, `std::async` is **much** more likely to do `pthread_create` than `fork`.

Comment: @StephenNewell: OP has to be aware that there is a difference before he can ask about it.  On some platforms, there *isn't* a difference.

Comment: Using fork the "slave " computation is made in another memory space. You can't expect to easily get the computed value back to your original one. Threads are execution in the same process. Fork creates a new process which like all processes is isolated from others.

Answer (score 2):

The key difference is that in the case of `std::async`, the two threads of execution share a process. In the case of `fork`, they each have their own process.

This difference most significantly affects things that change after the call. In the case of `fork`, each process can then open and close its own file descriptors, manage its own memory space, and so on. In the case of `std::async`, the threads continue to share file descriptors, memory space, and so on.

Answer (score 2):

### `fork()`

[`fork()`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) creates a child *process* by duplicating the calling process. The child process is detached from the parent process so each has its own memory and without setting up any inter-process communication channels it is impossible to pass data between the two processes. The most common use case for calling `fork()` is to start a process as a background service (a.k.a. "daemon"). For example when you start your favorite web server on the command line, it might fork off a child process (the actual server process). Once that's done the main process ends so control returns back to your shell and you can do other things.

### `std::async`

[`std::async`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) executes a function in a separate *thread* (assuming policy `std::launch::async`). It returns a `std::future` on which you can call `get()` to get the value returned by the function (assuming it returned and didn't throw an exception). The `get()` call returns immediately if the function has completed in the meantime, otherwise it blocks until the function has returned. This feature makes `std::async` a useful tool for running expensive computations in the background while doing something else.